# AMCL drift rotation

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have an AMCL drift problem when the robot rotates around itself. The most serious problem occurs if it performs small rotations, for example <15º, as this video I recorded. If the robot moves back and forth AMCL works perfectly.

[video showing the problem](https://youtu.be/BYLf2jtDpzA)

[image: rqt_graph]

[image: rqt_tf_tree]

I have already checked the wheelbase and it is correct.

Is this expected? or is there a parameter to fix this problem?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337782/amcl-drift-rotation/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-11-17**:
Are you sure you have your robot otherwise set up correctly?

**Comment by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on 2019-11-17**:
Thanks for your time. If that helps, I added some images from "rqt_graph / rqt_tf_tree". Do not hesitate to ask me for more information, I am learning ROS and I have many doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Before integrating with AMCL I would suggest to take a look at section 1 on the [Navigation Stack Troubleshooting](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Troubleshooting) page, this will make sure that you are estimating the odometry correctly:

> 1. Is My Odometry Good Enough for AMCL Problem: The robot doesn't seem to be
>    localized properly. Its position
>    estimate jumps around a lot in rviz
>    and the navigation stack doesn't seem
>    able to follow the plans produced by
>    the global planner. Is this a problem
>    with AMCL or my robot's odometry.
>
> Solution: There are a couple of tests
> that are helpful to run to see how
> good the odometry of a robot is:
>
> Test 1: Open up rviz and make sure
> that you're subscribed to the laser
> scan topic for your robot. Next, set
> the decay time to something like 30
> seconds. Also set the fixed frame to
> the odom frame. Perform an in-place
> rotation with the robot and look at
> the laser scans. If odometry is fairly
> accurate, you should see scans from
> the previous rotation overlap with
> those generated on the current
> rotation. You'll want to do this in an
> area where you have distinctive
> features in your laser scan.
>
> Test 2:Set up rviz the same way as the
> previous test. Point the robot at a
> wall and drive it towards it. With
> good odometry, the wall should stay in
> about the same place as the robot
> moves towards it. If you see a lot of
> movement in the positions of the scans
> relative to the wall that means
> odometry is poor.
>
> Test 3: Drive the robot straight down
> a hallway. The laser scans of the
> hallway should stay straight. If you
> see them move a lot, it means your
> odometry is poor.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2